# How do I ignore a line when using the pdb?

Tags: python, pdb

For some quick Python debugging I'll occasionally throw in a `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` line that will drop me into the debugger.  Very handy.  However, if I want to debug a loop, that may run many, many, many times, it loses its effectiveness somewhat.  I could mash on `c`ontinue  many, many, many times, but is there a way to remove/ignore that hard-coded breakpoint so I can let it finish?

I could set a global flag and run it conditionally, but then I'd lose the 'standalone-ness' of the one-line breakpoint, also requiring another flag for each `pdb.set_trace()`.

Answer (score 2):

My other answer is sort of a quick hack, and is not perfect (will disable **all** calls to `set_trace`).  Here's a better solution.

We define a module wrapping `pdb`. In it, `set_trace` is a callable object, maintaining a list of disabled callers (identified by filename/line-number).

```
# mypdb.py
import inspect
import sys
try:
    import ipdb as PDB
except ImportError:
    import pdb as PDB

class SetTraceWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.callers_disabled = set()
        self.cur_caller = None
    def __call__(self):
        self.cur_caller = self.get_caller_id()
        if self.cur_caller in self.callers_disabled:
            # already disabled for caller
            #print 'set_trace SKIPPED for %s' % ( self.cur_caller, )
            return
        #print 'set_trace BREAKING for %s' % ( self.cur_caller, )
        try:
            PDB.set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)
        except TypeError:
            PDB.set_trace()
    def disable_current(self):
        #print 'set_trace DISABLING %s' % ( self.cur_caller, )
        self.callers_disabled.add(self.cur_caller)
    def get_caller_id(self, levels_up = 1):
        f = inspect.stack()[levels_up + 1]
        return ( f[1], f[2] )  # filename and line number

set_trace = SetTraceWrapper()
```

In your code, make sure you use the wrapper:

```
import mypdb as pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

When you want to disable the current `set_trace`-calling-line, do:

```
pdb.set_trace.disable_current()
```

Notes:

1. I personally prefer `ipdb` over `pdb`
2. When using `pdb`, since the function actually calling `pdb.set_trace` is in the wrapper, the current frame when breaking will be in it.  the `up` command gets you the to frame you want.  This will not happen if using `ipdb` (the implementation in the wrapper makes sure to break in the right place).
3. When using `ipdb`, I find it to report caller-frame line-numbers inconsistently.  This means the first time you do `pdb.set_trace.disable_current()`, it might not hold.  Just do it again if it breaks the next time -- the second time holds.
4. In general, having your own `pdb` wrapper is useful for other things as well.  I have my own `set_trace` wrapper which avoids breaking if `not sys.stdout.isatty` (you never want to break if the process is not connected to a terminal, nor when you redirect the stdout to a file/pipe).  That is to say, having your own `pdb` wrapper and calling its `set_trace` instead of `pdb`'s is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The following hack will disable **all other calls** to `set_trace` in current run (i.e., from anywhere in your code).

Create this `noop_pdb` drop-in:

```
# noop_pdb.py
def set_trace(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Then, once your code breaks in the real `pdb.set_trace`, and you want to disable the rest of the calls to `set_trace`, do:

```
sys.modules['pdb'] = __import__('noop_pdb')
```

Next time the interpreter encounters a line like:

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

It avoids re-importing the built-in `pdb`, picking up the drop-in.

EDIT: another way to implement this hack, which does not require `noop_pdb`, is by replacing `set_trace` with noop, instead of the whole `pdb` module: `pdb.set_trace = lambda: None`

Comment: pdb.set_trace = lambda: None just saved me from a situation where it would have been very painful to restart my script

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at `condition bpnumber` ? You could disable the breakpoint and then make it conditional. Alternatively you could just use `break` or `tbreak` to make the breakpoint conditional in the first place. Details can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "until" command that's provided by pdb?

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands:

> **unt(il)**
>
> Continue execution until the line with the line number greater
>   than the current one is reached or when returning from current frame.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'return' in pdb can pass pdb.set_trace() in the loop and jump to the last line of the current function.